# CSS para estilizar Total do WooCommerce

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Estou montando uma loja virtual no `wordpress` e gostaria de saber como eu faço pra estilizar o `Total` no topo do site. Atualmente ele fica quebrado, como se tivessem dado um `block` entre o `R$` e o valor.

Fica mais ou menos assim:

```
R$
290,00
```

Eu preciso que fique assim `R$ 290,00`

O site é [www.clicfeira.com.br](http://www.clicfeira.com.br)

Basta adicionar um produto e atualizar e na sequencia, gostaria de saber se alguém consegue solucionar comigo, pra que eu possa adicionar o produto no carrinho, e o mesmo mudar a quantidade e o valor em tempo real no topo.

Comment: Alisson, cara, adiciona o trecho do código em que está o problema para que possamos te ajudar, da maneira como está, não temos como te ajudar, existem inúmeras respostas para resolver esse problema, mas depende de como está o seu código. Procure também focar em uma pergunta somente, se precisar de ajuda com outras coisas, considere [criar outra pergunta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Agora consegui acessar o site, porém não consegui ver o problema que está acontecendo.

Comment: O site está aparecendo com o preço no formato desejado, apague os cookies de seu navegador e recarregue a página. Pois as alterações é estão feita.

Comment: Não está não mano, eu desativei aqui, vou colocar o preço total, pra aparecer no topo e vcs fazem o teste.

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Pra mim está aparecendo assim:
[image: para mim os valor total está ok]

O que você está tendo dificuldade para fazer?

Comment: Pessoal, essa parte conseguir resolver, obrigado a todos! Eu apenas removi um span do woocommerce com uma classe